# sh file not running on cron ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, cron

I am trying to run a shell script on `crontab` on Ubuntu platform. I have tried googling and other links but nothing has helped so far.

This is my `crontab`:

```
*/2 * * * *  sudo bash /data/html/mysite/site_cleanup.sh
```

This is the content of my `sh` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
# How many days retention do we want ?
DAYS=0

# geting present day 
now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")

# Where is the base directory
BASEDIR=/data/html/mysite

#where is the backup directory
BKPDIR=/data/html/backup

# Where is the log file
LOGFILE=$BKPDIR/log/mysite.log

# add to tar 
tar -cvzf $now.tar.gz $BASEDIR

mv $now.tar.gz $BKPDIR

# REMOVE OLD FILES
echo `date` Purge Started >> $LOGFILE
find $BASEDIR -mtime +$DAYS | xargs rm
echo `date` Purge Completed >> $LOGFILE
```

The same script runs from a terminal and gives the desired result.

Comment: I guess you don't have a user called "sudo", if this is `/etc/crontab`, replace `sudo` with `root`.

Comment: my bad i didn't kept any sudo, */2 * * * *  bash /data/html/mysite/site_cleanup.sh. thanks paulo

Comment: Where is this crontab file? I mean, is it under `/etc/` or is it edited with `crontab -e`?

Comment: it is edited with crontab -e

Comment: Add `SHELL=/bin/sh` in the beginning of the crontab and run a `chmod a+rx site_cleanup.sh`, then you can omit `bash` in front of the script. Also check your email, the output of the job is sent to the email of your shell user. Good luck figuring this out.

Comment: i tried but no luck, what i am missing, anyway thanks for quick response

Comment: Is the cron daemon running?  Try `ps -ef | grep crond`.

Comment: Note that cron-started scripts have a very tiny environment. Sometimes even `PATH` is not set or too restricted. Your script must set the `PATH` it needs. Start with `PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH)`.

Comment: `xargs rm` is dangerous. And running the script as root does not make it any safer. Please see [BashFAQ 20](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)

Comment: As an aside, your `#!/bin/sh` does nothing if you start it with `bash` -- the latter controls, making this a bash script, not a POSIX sh script.

Comment: @PauloScardine, eh? `bash` could be omitted just as easily without setting `SHELL`.

Comment: To determine *where* this is hanging, consider using `exec 2>/path/to/logfile` (to log stderr to a file) and `set -x` (to log names and arguments of commands run) near the front of your script.

Comment: ...though if it's the `sudo` call that's failing, as @eBooks_Nashville suggests, that log file won't be created at all -- itself a useful data point.

Answer (score 2):

## Generic troubleshooting for noninteractive shell scripts

Put `set -x; exec 2>/path/to/logfile` at the top of your script to log all subsequent commands to a file as they're run. If this doesn't work, you'll know that your script isn't being run at all; if it does, you'll know where it fails and how.

## If this is a personal crontab

If you're running `crontab -e` as a user (without `sudo`), then the crontab being modified is one for commands run with that user's permissions. Check that file permissions allow that user to modify the content in question (which, if these files are in a `cgi-bin` directory, may require being run by the same user as the web server).

If your *intent* is to have commands run as root, rather than as your own user, be sure you use `sudo` when editing the crontab to edit the system crontab instead (but please take care as to your script's correctness in this case -- carelessness such as missing quotes or lack of appropriate precautions in `xargs` usage can cause a script to delete the wrong files if malicious filenames are created):

```
sudo crontab -e             ## to edit the system (root) crontab
```

...or, if you're cleaning up files owned by the `apache` user (for example; check which account is correct for your own operating system and web server):

```
sudo -u apache crontab -e   ## to edit the apache user's crontab
```

## Troubleshooting for a system crontab

**Do not** attempt to put a `sudo` command *within* the commands run by `cron`; with `sudo`'s default configuration, it requires a TTY (a keyboard and screen) to be attached to a session in order to run. Thus, your crontab line should not contain `sudo`, but instead should look like the following:

```
*/2 * * * *  bash /data/html/mysite/site_cleanup.sh
```

Comment: `source` would be using `/bin/sh` (unless there's a `SHELL=` line in the crontab's header), significantly changing behavior.

Comment: Reconstructing, I think the downvote was because this struck me more as a list of questions than a canonical answer (some of them unlikely to be fruitful; a cron job running as root, for instance, isn't particularly likely to be lacking read access). Granted, sometimes the OP doesn't give enough information to build a canonical answer, but encouraging addition of information to an inadequate question is what comments are for.

Comment: I've tried to edit this to remove questions of uncertain relevance and speak in a more canonical tone. Feel free to roll back (and/or let me know) if you think I've been overly heavy-handed.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is likely coming from the sudo call from your user level cron. Unless you've gone through and edited the bashrc profile to allow that script to run without sudo it'll hang up every time.

So you can lookup how to run a script with no password by modifying the bashrc profile, remove the sudo call if you aren't doing something in your script that calls for Super User permissions, or as a last ditch, extremely bad idea you can call your script from root's cron by doing `sudo crontab -e` or `sudo env EDITOR=nano crontab -e` if you prefer nano as your editor.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this line to the crontab of user root and without the sudo.
like this:

```
*/2 * * * * bash /data/html/mysite/site_cleanup.sh
```

Comment: The `bash` is useless if the script has a proper hash-bang.

Comment: Well -- the `bash` is overriding the shebang, which would be using `/bin/sh` itself if left to its own devices.